# If we say A is weaker than B by a factor of x, then should x be smaller or bigger than 1?

Tags: grammar, comparisons

In math, we always need to derive different algorithms to get a tighter error bound. It may be correct almost surely that: the error bound of B is better than that of A by a factor x (x is bigger than 1). However, I am not sure if it is right to say:  the error bound of A is weaker than that of B by a factor x (x is samller than 1)?

Comment: There is no defined relationship between strength and size.

Comment: Based on the answer you selected, it looks like this was a math problem and not an English language problem. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intuition is that you use the number bigger than 1, and [Googling bears me out](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bigger+by+a+factor+of%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22smaller+by+a+factor+of%22).

Answer (score 4):

#### If B is better than A by a factor of x, then A is weaker than B by a factor of x.

Not only is it correct, but it is equivalent to this statement:

#### If B == A * x, then A == B / x

There should be *no* restriction on `x` though. No need to say (x bigger than 1) or (x smaller than 1). Whatever `x` is in one statement, it should be the same in the other.

Take the starting statement: `B is better than A by a factor of x`. What "*better*" means can be confusing since it is unique to your exact problem, so I'll just use the *value* (rather than the algorithm) of B and compare that with the *value* of A.

Now we have: `B > A by a factor of X`.

The phrase "*by a factor of*, means when either increasing or decreasing a value by multiplying it by some factor. Since we are measuring how "good" an algorithm is, we aren't just comparing two numbers on the normal scale.
If we have a logarithmic scale (base 10) where 5 is the worst an algorithm can perform, and 8 is the best an algorithm can perform, then the values 6 is better than the value 5 by a factor of 10. Similarly, 5 is worse than 6 by a factor of 10.

Below I provide links and show details about how to find this equation, but in this section I'll only solve it.

If we have some initial value, `i`, and we increase it by a factor of some unknown, `x`, and we end at some final value, `f`, we can solve for the factor:

```
(f / i) == f
```

If we had decreased `i` by a factor of `x` and ended at `f`, we could solve for the factor like this:

```
(f / i) == (1 / f)
```

See the inverse relationship?

We can use this to show that A is weaker than B by a factor of X.

```
Initial value = A
Final value   = B
Factor        = X

(A / B) = X

(B / A) = 1 / X
```

So to get the factor, when we increase A by a factor of X to get to B, we find the factor is X. And if we decrease by a factor, i.e. go from B to A, we take the inverse and see the factor is 1/X.

If we give X a number, let's say 5, we can see the property in action:

```
(A / B) = 5
  => A = 5B

(B / A) = (1 / 5)
  => B = 1/5A
```

You can plug in either value of A or B into the other equation to see they are both true.

---

The usage of saying that some value is *decreased* by a factor of some value isn't too common in pure mathematics (excluding grammar school math), but you do see it in branches like [economics](https://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/tutorials/exp/factor.html) and [physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoT8ITxwepg).

See the definition of *factor* according to the [Cambridge Dictionary's listing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/factor):

> a ​number or ​variable (= ​letter or ​symbol) that is being ​multiplied in a ​product (= ​result of ​multiplying):

According to this definition, a factor is simply some number or variable being multiplied to another.

---

We can use the definition of "*factor*" to see how the following examples make sense:

> Suppose you invested $100, and after a time, your investment was worth $300. The final value ($300) would be three (3) times the initial value. We would say that your investment had increased by a factor of 3.
>
> On the other hand, if you made a poor investment, and the value decreased from $100 to $25, then the final value would be a quarter (1/4) of the initial value. We would say the investment had decreased by a factor of 4.

[This short article](https://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/tutorials/exp/factor.html) goes on to show how the final value divided by the initial value is equal to the factor when increasing a value by a factor. It also shows the factor is the reciprocal of that value when decreasing by a factor.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the common usage may be, "decreased by a factor of" is confusing, and should be deprecated. Rather say *decreased to (state the fraction here) of* instead: *decreased to a quarter of*, for example.
One of the reasons the *decreased by* usage is bad, is that it's used to mean what it shouldn't. If you say *decreased by a factor of 4*, then what factor of 4 are you talking about - 1, 2, 4? B is not decreased by a factor of the decrease, the factor you're talking about has to be a factor of B!

Do you mean you end up with what you started with, less 1/4, or 1/4 of what you started with? In the first case, starting with 100, you end up with 75; in the second, with 25.
This is not all. It leads to something like *rainfall has decreased by 200%*, which means we must somehow be giving rain back. Starting with 100mm, for example, we now have -100mm.
Journalists tend to use this style a lot, which just proves that innumeracy is part of their job description.

Comment: +1 Frank, I think you had some really notable points that *needed* to be said. I completely agree that the usage of "decreased by a factor of" should be deprecated, ***especially*** outside of the colloquial of mathematics. However, I did feel that from reading your post it seemed as though there was absolutely no common practice or understanding of the phrase, even within mathematics. I disagree with that particular point. I think that in mathematics (and **only** mathematics), there is an agreed practice for the usage of the phrase. See my answer for what that exact usage is.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. All through my answer, I'm referring to common usage. Mathematicians know what they're talking about: if they didn't, it wouldn't be mathematics!

Answer (score -1):

if **B = A*x** and **A** weaker than **B** then **x** should be greater than **1**.

**Example** :

*First one*:

`A = 2; x = 5;// (x>1)`

`B = 2*5 = 10; //A weaker than B`

*Second one*:

`A = 2; x = 0.8;// (x<1)`

`B = 2*0.8 = 1.6; //B weaker than A`